# Routing to different pages based on whether or not user is logged in. - Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

in config/routes.rb, I have:

```
root to: "pages#home"
get "/visitor" => "pages#visitor"
```

In my controllers/application_controller.rb, I have:

```
before_filter :route_relative_to_login_state_and_role

private

def route_relative_to_login_state_and_role
    if current_user
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to visitor_path
    end
end
```

In my controllers/pages_controller.rb, I have:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:home]

  def home
    @page_title = t ('home_page_title')
  end

  def visitor
    @page_title = t ('visitor_page_title')
  end

end
```

Here's my views/pages/home.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @page_title %></h1>
```

Here's my views/pages/visitor.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @page_title %></h1>
```

This is from the output of rake routes:

```
    visitor GET    /visitor(.:format)                       pages#visitor
```

When I start the server and point my browser to htp://localhost:3000 the browser tells me that the page is not redirecting properly. Here's what the log file says:

```
Started GET "/visitor" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-15 10:37:46 -0700
Processing by PagesController#visitor as HTML
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/visitor
Filter chain halted as :route_relative_to_login_state_and_role rendered or redirected
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly if the user logged_in you what to redirect to page and if not to another page, what you did is wrong and you can control it from ApplicationController and do something like:

```
before_filter :check_user

def check_user
   if current_user
       ## this is logged user
       redirect_to first_path
   else
       ## this is unlogged user
       redirect_to second_path
   end
end
```

hope that's what you meant.

Comment: Yes, this is the net effect of what I want to do, but if the user is not logged in, there would be no current_user, so your code would return an error?

Comment: no, my code contain else so if current_user is not present you will send him to the second url, you understand?

Comment: The `current_user` method exists regardless. It would simply return `nil` if the user is not logged in.

Comment: this is very simple `if current_user` mean if it present(not nil) if it is present(user logged in) user will be redirected to `first_path` if it nil(no user!!) `else` is executed and user will be redirected to `second_path`, very simple code. i think you need to read devise documentation. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: I was essentially asking about current_user. My understanding was that it was present (using Devise), but I was getting an undefined method message for current_user. I am not getting that (it may have been a Devise issue). I was also wondering how Rails may react is presented with a nil, but that could be handled using an unless or check for nil (if that's an issue). I am still getting an error, please see my revised question